# Is possible have byte from 0 to 255 in java?

Tags: java, c#, primitive-types

I have system (in **c#**) to control user access.
I need to have the same access controller in **java** for an specific case.
This controller has a criptography algorithm (rijndael).
My problem is that this algorithm uses arrays of bytes (`byte[]`); and this *byte* type in **c#** is `0 to 255`, and in **java** is `-128 to 127`. This difference generate differents results.

How can I make those two codes to use the same *byte array*?

PS: I can't change the c# code; if I could, I would use sbyte instead of byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read an unsigned byte[] into a signed byte[] none of the bits are harmed in this progress and no data is lost.  The difference is only how the top bit is treated.  If you want to turn a signed byte in a value between 0 and 255 you can & it with 0xFF e.g.

```
int value = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
```

Comment: my problem is bigger than this. i'm using a native java function that receive my 'bytes[]' ('SecretKeySpec(byte[] key, String algorithm)'). i really need to send an array of bytes..

Comment: That will _work_ if you use Java signed bytes.  It will still work identically.

Comment: @rLinhares I use byte manipulation to native memory all the time (even today) it doesn't have to be a problem.

Comment: i need create a `SecretKeySpec` (http://goo.gl/BA4lb1) and it requires a `byte[]`. In this cast we transform _byte_ in _int_ and I still not able to create the _SecretKeySpec_.

Answer (score 1):

Someone developed a library for unsigned types you might be able to use:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOU